# Change an existing FileStream's 'FileShare' from 'Read' to 'None'

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I want to open a file and block others from writing to it, but allow them to read it. Then after some calculations, I want to block reads as well while I write to it, so no process gets a partially written file.

However, while it seems that I can specify creation of a `FileStream` with either `FileShare.Read` or `FileShare.None`, I can't seem to find a way to start out with `FileShare.Read` and then change to `FileShare.None`.

The reason I don't want to create a *new* `FileStream` (with `FileShare.None`) is because I don't want any changes to be made to the file while I shift from the old `FileStream` to the new one.

```
using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None))
{
     ...
}
```

Comment: What potentially happens if changes are made to the file in the small amount of time it takes to change streams?  Is what might happen important enough to invest in a first-class ACID capable data store like an RDBMS?

Comment: It is not an accident that you must provide the value in the constructor. The OS you use does not support changing it after you opened the file. It is in good company, none of them do. It is not obvious what paddle you want to use to get that boat upstream, you can moor it half-way, but it is no doubt going to sink before it gets there.  The file system is not a synchronization primitive, you have to add it yourself.

Comment: Is the file large?   Can you just read it all into memory?

Comment: @RobertHarvey It's actually code that I want to have _instead_ of the current SQL Server which is overkill (the SQL that is). But according to Hans' comment, it looks like I have no choice but to stick to SQL.

Comment: @Ctznkane525 That would be great. Unfortunately, it's on Asp.Net where one of the gotchas is that the whole application gets recycled every so often.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks. That seems to be the answer. And I assume that if you say it can't be done, it can't be done. You can transform it into an answer so I can accept it.